# How to set a read only in ruby views

Tags: html, css, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i do this but not working for me

```
    <div class="row form-group">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <%='start_date'%><span class="necessary-field">  *</span>:
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 select">
     <%= calendar_date_select_tag'start_date',@employee.job.start_date, :readonly=>true, :format=>:default,  :popup=>"force", :class=>"form-control" %>
  </div>
</div>
```

i used :readonly=>true but also not working

how for example to us (input )

Comment: `calendar_date_select_tag` is not a build-on Ruby on Rails method. What gem do you use that provides this method?

Comment: sir @spickermann what if i use <input >